# HC 05 Bluetooth Module Not Connecting with Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I am doing a project Smart cane Companion for Blind people to guide them to walk avoiding the obstacle in their path.
It involves pairing  Android phone with the HC 05 bluetooth module.
The HC 05 bluetooth module is connected to Arudino UNO board.
The HC 05 is not connecting with Android.
Here is the connect code that I have written on android.
Note : This activity lists the paired devices in the form of a listview and the address and name of the devices are gotten from the previous activity.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by Stealth on 20-04-2016.
 */
public class PairingList extends Activity
{
    ListView lview;
    String paires[];
    String macs[];
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String btdevices[];
    BluetoothSocket btSocket;
    BluetoothDevice device;
    BluetoothAdapter btadapter;
    int BLUETOOTH_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pairinglist);
        lview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewid);
        btadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Bundle bn = getIntent().getExtras();
        paires = bn.getStringArray("paires");
        macs = bn.getStringArray("macs");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,paires);
        lview.setAdapter(adapter);
        lview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String address = macs[position];
                device = btadapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
                try {
                    btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"e" + "     "+ address,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                btadapter.cancelDiscovery();
                try {
                    btSocket.connect();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Connected to Device",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
                catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"e1"+"     " + address,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


            }
        });

    }
}
```

The Problem is exception e1 always triggers.
I have the MAC address of the HC 05 module in address
MAC address is 98:D3:31:40:9A:D2
THE HC 05 IS STILL NOT CONNECTING WITH ANDROID ANY HELP WILL BE  MUCH APPRECIATED
THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Obviously, the blind man who's going to install your app has a device with a Braille display.

Comment: No,really. Do you need a smartphone for that? An IR obstacle detector connected to an Arduino NANO (because it's much smaller than an Arduino UNO and can be fit into the stick handle) driving a buzzer is more than enough.

Comment: I plan to give audio updates to the person via the phone thus I need to connect it with HC 05 so if you can please do help buddy It would be much appreciated

Comment: It's really a broad question. I suggest you to find some tutorial on how to make Android and Arduino communicate through BT. But I'm not inclined to believe that a blind person would ever buy a smartphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try changing the UUID to "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"? I've connected HC-05 to an Android device in the past using this uuid.

Or you could try using getUuids() to find all the published services and their associated UUID values for each device discovered by Bluetooth and then use the UUID which works.

Comment: It would be much better to **discover** the UUIDs of the nearby devices, rather than providing **predefined** ones. Also mind that *each device has a different UUID*. Therefore, your UUID is not valid for the OP.

Comment: I tried that UUID . the same exception gets triggered

Comment: I used that UUID with block letters and it wasnt connecting and when I gave small letters it was connecting In all online codes I read UUID contained block letters Thanks a lot